# How to "hibernate a process" under Linux/Windows?

Tags: windows, linux, process

Just like e.g. people can press Ctrl+P when running a VirtualBox guest, it can pause the guest, after pressing again Ctrl+P it will continue right there where it was stopped. Are there any command line commands on Windows/Linux where I can do the same with a process? (the process is e.g.: Firefox, etc.)
Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Windows, you want [PsSuspend](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897540.aspx). The utility demands a PID, which is a column you can add in [Task Manager](http://www.mydigitallife.info/how-to-get-and-view-process-identifier-process-id-or-pid-on-windows/).

For Linux, seconding the [above](http://tombuntu.com/index.php/2007/11/23/how-to-pause-a-linux-process/). kill -STOP and kill -CONT.

Comment: Also with the Process Explorer tool (also by Sysinternals), you can do this in one step from the GUI. Process Explorer can also be configured to show a lot more information than the standard task manager.

Answer (score 3):

`pstop` will generally work on Linux and other Unixes which implement `/proc`-based process control (many System Vs, almost no BSDs); `kill -TSTP` (`-TSTP` should be used with interactive processes; `-STOP` may be better for daemons) will work on most modern Unixes.  The reverse operation is `prun` or `kill -CONT`, respectively.  Note that these are not necessarily equivalent; on Solaris they are entirely distinct operations.

Answer (score 0):

Not aware of a command line tool but on windows if you install AnVir Task Manager Free you can select a task and suspend it, then resume at a later time.